# The search of product name, SKU does not get the exact result in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento2.3.4, magento-search

I am using Magento 2.3.4. I want to get the exact search result using SKU or product name but currently get the related results. Please help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you reindex? what search engine are you using? where are you searching?

Comment: Hello @PhilippSander, Default search magento search engine use and searching product using name and sku but search result get related product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search functionality is working as when you search any keyword then this keyword looking in the product description, short-description, name, and SKU or enabled search attribute settings.

if you  want to get the exact search result using only SKU or product name you can disable another attribute search settings

**path:** Stores > Attributes > Product > [Attributes]

[image]

And Increase search Weight of SKU and Name like(1 to 10)

[image]

If in your project enable **Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation** then try to disable it because sometimes it affects the search result.

> Run CLI commands

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:clean
```